# Ajax form post with multi selected checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, model-view-controller

I'm unable to post this form with UserId and Multi select checkbox as a list using ajax post.

```
<html>
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>
        <form  method="POST" >
        <div> <input type="Text" name='UserId'  value="Ram" ></div>
        <div id="Activity">
          <input type="checkbox" name="aa" Id="bb_1" value="1" >
          <input type="checkbox" name="aa"  Id="bb_2" value="2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="aa" Id="bb_3" value="3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="aa"  Id="bb_4" value="4">
          <input type="checkbox" name="aa" Id="bb_5" value="5">
         </div>  
          <input type="submit" class="button-default" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

<script>
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
           var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
           $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:55798/API/Applyjob",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                });
 e.preventDefault();
           $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
          window.location.reload();
 });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to post this form with multi selected checkbox value like as a list. Then how to post this form using ajax form post method?

Comment: What tech is the backend using? This is important is choosing the correct mutli-value serialisation data format

Comment: what about using $('form').serialize() in data value

Comment: What @GüneySaramalı says is a nice way to do that. Maybe it's just because of sample code, but now the page will be reloaded by location.reload() and the form doesn't have a preventDefault  (to prevent submitting by default that means the page will be reloaded anyway). So in this sample it looks like ajax can be left out ;).